# What does the statement "a class is an object even if not instantiated" mean?

Tags: c++, ruby, class

I'm a C++ programmer learning Ruby. In a beginner book I read:

*"A class is itself an object, even if you don’t directly instantiate it."*

I don't know how to interpret that.

Comment: I guess this makes sense.  A class, as an object, contains metadata about the properties of itself.  You can query for what methods and properties it has, pass around type data, etc.  However, I'll wait for some Ruby expert to chime in with a lengthy and detailed answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++, with the exception of `typeid` et al, there's no language-visible runtime representation of a class. You can say `class Foo {};`, but then you can't say `&Foo`. (You can get the `typeid` / address of the `typeinfo` object, which is a bastardized version of a class object).

In Ruby, classes are objects. Anything you can do with an object, you can do with a class since it is an object. For example, in Ruby you can `foo.send(...)` to any object `foo`. Since a class is an object, you can just as well as `Foo.send(...)`.

The part about "you didn't instanciate it" refers to the fact that usually you say `foo = Foo.new` in Ruby but you don't need to say that for classes. The class object is created by the runtime. (In fact, `class Foo; end` in Ruby is pretty similar to `Foo = Class.new`.)

Comment: Then in the statement above the part "even if you don't instantiate it" is slightly misleading.  I take it that although perhaps the programmer has not explicitly instantiated the class, it is still in fact instantiated somewhere?

Comment: @drb, instantiating a class means creating an object based on that class. The class itself is not an instantiation of the class, but a different kind of object altogether.

Comment: The point is you don't usually directly instantiate class objects. It means "even though you didn't call `#new` on any class object to create the Foo class object". The class instantiation is implicit. This is also important because classes are open in Ruby. You can say `class Foo; end` multiple times in Ruby. The class object is only created once; any additional class definitions add to it. That's one reason `Foo = new Class` is not quite the same thing as `class Foo;end`.

Comment: Was `Foo = new Class` meant to be pseudo-C++ ? It's not valid Ruby.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewGrimm. Fixed (at least in the answer body). Switching back and forth between Ruby and C++ today.

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby, everything is an object. That includes classes. So when you declare

```
class Thing
end
```

You've made an instance of the `Class` class called `Thing`. It's identical to

```
Thing = Class.new
```

which would be "directly instantiating" the instance of `Class`.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in Ruby is an object, even the classes themselves.

```
class Test
  def self.foo
    "bar"
  end
  def yin
    "yang"
  end
end

# This creates a new instance and calls #yin
Test.new.yin # => "yang"

# This calls the #foo method on the Test class object.
Test.foo     # => "bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

In some other languages, you have something called 'abstract classes'. These things are not objects themselves and can't really do anything. They're really more like a template for creating an actual object. An actual object can do things like run methods, accept arguments, etc. An abstract class can't do any of that and exists mainly to create a real object. When an object is created from them, it's called 'instantiating' an object.

Now in ruby, you don't have abstract classes. The class you use to derive objects from (instantiate) is sort of like an abstract class in some ways. But unlike abstract classes, this class in ruby can already do things itself.

This is what the statement you quoted "A class is itself an object, even if you don’t directly instantiate it" is trying to make clear. It isn't virtual in the sense of an abstract class. Rather it's already a full fledged object.

Answer (score 0):

All this really means is that you can treat Classes just as you can instances of these classes.

```
class Animal; end
bird = Animal.new
```

You can now work with `Animal` just as you could with `bird`.

e.g.

```
Animal.methods => 'list of methods'
bird.methods => 'list of methods'
```

That's all there is to it really.